# How to assign value of one filed from an object to a local variable IN WEB API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, web

please help how can I assign specific value to local local variable.
well I have a method which get me an object from database and I want to assign specific value from this object to this variable

```
public string ITMTable(string GR)
{
    ImpITM ImpITM = new ImpITM();
    var item = ImpITM.Imp_ITM(GR);
    string item_name = item.item_name.where(a => a.id == GR);

    return item_name;
}
```

I want do something like this please help

Comment: It is not clear to me where you are stuck. The provided code does not compile, but you are not really saying anything about that. Can you try to explain what you don't understand about your current code that you need help with?

Comment: will I just want to assign the value from "item_name" field from the object I got from method"Imp_ITM" to local variable "item_name"